# How to access a static IP assigned to a device by LAN connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ip, static-ip

My device has a static IP assigned (192.168.1.2). I have this device (DVR) plugged into a PC via LAN Ethernet. When I first bought the system I was able to access the device "server" locally by entering the static IP into the address bar. I no longer can.

The settings on the device are as follows:

```
Type: Static
Remote Port: 9000
Local Port: 80
IP: 192.168.1.2
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.0
DNS: 192.168.1.0
Auto Port Forwarding: OFF
```

On a Windows 7 PC, what are the correct settings/method(s) to access the static IP when connected directly (Device-to-PC) via LAN?

Edit: What are some common reasons this would not be functioning as normal? Is there an easier way? DHCP? I have 1 device and 1 PC, just need it to "plug-n-play" so to speak, where I can pull up its IP in the connected PC's browser.

Comment: If you have solved this, please tell us, so we can stop thinking about it. If you haven’t solved it, please [edit] the question and post the information you previously posted in comments under the answer (nobody will see it there).

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 PC needs to have an IP address on its LAN interface in the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet) as the device, i.e., it needs an address in the range 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254. You could give it the IP address 192.168.1.3, if it doesn't, provided no other device on the LAN has that address, though it might be safer to pick something higher in the range, e.g., 192.168.1.200 if you have other devices on the LAN, but you don't know their IP addresses. Use the same subnet mask on the Windows 7 PC, i.e., 255.255.255.0

**Update:** Is your DVR device plugged into a device, such as a router, that is functioning as a [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server? If it is plugged into a router that is functioning as a DHCP server and other devices that are also plugged into the same router are receiving DHCP-assigned IP addresses, e.g., addresses from any of the [private network address blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces), if they are configured to receive addresses by DHCP, then the problem may be with the network interface in the DVR having an IP address that is not in the same subnet as the other devices on the LAN. You may simply need to configure the DVR to also receive an IP address via DHCP, so that it gets an address in the same subnet as the PC.

You haven't explained how your devices are connected. Do both the DVR and Windows 7 system plug into the same piece of network equipment, such as a network switch or router or do you have a cable directly from the PC to the DVR?  If the latter is the case, you might need a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_cable).

**Update 2:** If you are running a cable directly from the Ethernet port on the Windows system to the Ethernet port on the DVR, both have to be in the same subnet - you can see [8 Steps to Understanding IP Subnetting](https://www.techopedia.com/6/28587/internet/8-steps-to-understanding-ip-subnetting) for an explanation of how subnetting works. You could give both a static 192.168.1.x address where *x* is an address from 1 to 254 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. Be sure you apply the IP address on the Windows system to the LAN interface not a Wi-Fi interface, if you've got the two devices connected directly by a cable. There won't be a gateway system, i.e., a router if the systems are directly connected, but if you need to specify one, you could specify 192.168.1.1 and use a .2 address for the PC and a .3 address for the DVR. Note: if the PC is using a 192.168.1.x address for its Wi-Fi connectivity, which you can see by issuing an `ipconfig` command at a [command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/cmd_prompt.php), use another subnet, e.g., 192.168.2.x. The subnet mask can still be 255.255.255.0.

Not knowing details on the network interfaces of the two devices, I don't know if either of them has an [auto MD-X interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface) that would obviate the need for a crossover cable. You could give both devices an IP address and subnet mask that puts them in the same subnet and see if the straight through cable works. You may not need one, but if network connectivity still doesn't work, you could try a crossover cable like [these](https://www.showmecables.com/cat5e-crossover-patch-cable).

Comment: Running `ipconfig /all` on command prompt should show the correct info?

Comment: @ShopTech, yes that should provide the information.

Comment: I apologize, I actually think it's my equipment. As far as IPs go is .001 the same as .1 or is that .100? `ipconfig /all` comes up with an unusual IP when the device is plugged in (169.254.XXX.XX) and a mask of 255.255.0.0. Also comes up with an `arp -a`  command, gives these IPs: 224.0.0.2, 224.0.0.22, 224.0.0.252, and 255.255.255.255. Not a single IP is reachable, nor does it bring up the device menu that's supposed to be accessible from the Static IP of the device (also not found). Any pointers or is something malfunctioning? (will restore "correct answer", just hoping for add'l replies)

Comment: @ShopTech, yes ".1" is the same as ".001"; leading zeros are usually not displayed. The 224.x.x.x addresses are [multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) addresses as opposed to the unicast addresses you assign to network interfaces and aren't unusual. If you see a [169.x.x.x address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Address_autoconfiguration) that usually indicates that your system can't connect to a DHCP server or at least isn't getting a response from one. The Windows operating system will assign an IP address from the range 169.254.0.0 to 169.254.255.255 in such cases.

Comment: @ShopTech, I added some additional information to my post regarding things you might be able to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: It's a direct connection via LAN, yes. I do have a Wi-Fi repeater/bridge that I was able to get a connection from earlier, but I'm hoping for as simple and direct a connection as possible. Ok, the 169.254.XXX.XXX IP i'm getting should be "the IP" of the DVR? Should I change the "static IP setting" and mask of the DVR to match or leave as 192.168.1.2? Heading to work now to try all combinations of answer given. Any specifics on the type of crossover cable?

Comment: @ShopTech, I added some additional information to my post.